# InstallShield 2012: Install fails when IIS Virtual Dir set to be same property name as Component Destination

Tags: installshield

I have a property defined (it's value is set in a custom action) which is used to hold the directory location where the web app is to be installed. I set the "destination" value for the Feature to be this property as well as the "Virtual Directory/Content Source Path" for the web app in the "Internet Information Services" panel.

The web application is correctly copied to the destination folder.  If I were to use a different property, say [INSTALLDIR], the installation completes without error, but the IIS virtual dir points to the wrong location (INSTALLDIR does not match my installation location as I am installing multiple web apps and each has it's own property)

The installation rolls back and the following is found in the logs:

`CommitChanges for path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Testing/MSOW' and physical path 'C:\OtherInstalls\MSOW\'.  

CommitChanges failed with the following HRESULT: '-2147024891'.  

Error with IISRT: -2147024891
CustomAction ISIISInstall returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)  

Action ended 10:48:08: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.`

Do I just need a different property for the Virtual Dir?  Or am i just really confused?

Comment: Found this link:
http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=191914

So all I had to do what make sure my web.config file was not Read Only and my configuration with the property values works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some additional things to look out for (including the read-only web.config):

[Troubleshooting IIS Problems on Vista SP1](http://blog.iswix.com/2010/09/troubleshooting-iis-problems-on-vista.html)

Comment: My problem was read-only web.config too, and it was made read-only by TFS, I checked out the web.config, rebuild the setup project and it did ok.